# Download URL not present in Firebase Console

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

There is no url present in the file location of firebase storage. Instead it gives a storage path. Please help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFWAJ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download URLs are not/no longer automatically generated when you add a file to Cloud Storage through the Firebase SDK. Instead you will have to call [`getDownloadURL()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/StorageReference/getDownloadURL.html) to generate such a download URL. This URL will then also show up in the Firebase console.

Comment: This is very bad UX as it complicates the service and confuses people

Comment: Fair enough, but the answer doesn't handle the case of streaming a file to storage in firebase admin. I'm not finding the `getDownloadUrl()` method anywhere. (This is also an example of why it makes no sense to modify a method intended to GET and give it behaviors that make it POST -- it has odd side effects all across the codebase in other features)

Answer (score 1):

Just click the image and there is your URL:

[image]

To get the URL through Flutter, you can follow this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54086124/11231634

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for! Right click on the "Name" value shown in the image above and then you can copy the image's URL to your clipboard for pasting elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, in my case, some files cannot be downloaded as [Vitor suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63469259/1614120). I don't know why, but there's just a plain text instead of link.

[image]

**Solution**

Just download it via [Cloud Storage](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser) at Google Console. This works every time.