# How to load images from a folder in firebase storage and use it elsewhere

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to load images from a folder in firebase storage and the code is giving me this error
{type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'String'}
, I don't even know if this code achieves my purpose

```
class FireStorageService extends ChangeNotifier{
  FireStorageService();
  final storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
  static Future<dynamic> loadImage(String image) async{
    return await storage.ref('folder5/$image').getDownloadURL();
  }
}
Future<Widget> getImage() async {
  final url = await FireStorageService.loadImage('1.jpg');
  return Image.network(url);
}
```

Comment: What is the Future<T> of FireStorageService.loadImage() ??

Comment: @Mohamed Hussien Is your issue resolved?

Comment: Have a look at this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50877398/flutter-load-image-from-firebase-storage)

Answer (score 0):

Return `Future<String>` from `loadImage` function:

```dart
class FireStorageService extends ChangeNotifier{
  FireStorageService();
  
  static Future<String> loadImage(String image) async {
    return await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('folder5/$image').getDownloadURL();
  }
}

Future<Widget> getImage() async {
  final url = await FireStorageService.loadImage('1.jpg');
  return Image.network(url);
}
```